# Find largest (int) value in the (string) column with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a column looks like this:

```
sNumber          Value (String)   
A                10
b                50
c                90
d                Hi
e                !!!
f                #123
```

I want to search largest value which is 90 and then increment 1.

While in search, I want to ignore 'Hi' and any including characters.

I was successful to increment number by 1 to datatype int column.
Here is code below.

```
var sQuery =
    (from staff in db.Staffs where staff.sNumber >= 0
    orderby staff.sNumber ascending select staff.sNumber )
    .Distinct().ToList();

int counter = sQuery .Count;
snumber = sQuery [counter - 1];
dmlist.sNumber = snumber + 1;
```

Also I was able to write a code for MS SQL Query to find out my goal result.
But wasn't able to convert it to LINQ.

```
SELECT Convert(BIGINT, sNumber) As sNumber
  FROM DATABASE_NAME
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(sNumber) > 0
  ORDER BY sNumber desc
```

Is anyone can guide me to convert this MS SQL query to LINQ or better idea to get only numeric result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        List<String> column = new List<string>()
        {
            "12", "abc", "99", "!", "654"
        };

        var data = column.Where(x =>
        {
            decimal temp;
            return decimal.TryParse(x, out temp);
        }).Max(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x));
        data++;
```

Sadly if you want to do it in a LINQ query you need to parse things twice. You will first get a valid list of values. Then you need to get a max based on each valid item converted to a value type. Then you can modify the value as you see fit.

UPDATE -

Here is another option. You can iterate over each item converting it as you go. Any items that are not able to be converted just set them to NULL then eliminate them and then find max and increment it.

```
        Func<string, decimal?> stringToNullableDecimal = s =>
        {
            decimal temp;
            if (decimal.TryParse(s, out temp))
            {
                return temp;
            }
            return null;
        };
        List<string> column = new List<string>()
        {
            "12", "abc", "99", "!", "654"
        };
        var data = column.Select(x => stringToNullableDecimal(x)).Where(x => x.HasValue).Max();
        data++;
```

Comment: This is much better than using IsNumeric which has far too many holes to be accurate. Well done.

Comment: For the edge cases with only negative values mixed with other strings I would return `decimal.MinValue` if parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this also by creating a List of `Object` as shown below this way you will only need to can't the first parameter using the .ToString() and you can keep the Objects in their original form without having to change the Int32 values to a string by wrapping `""` around them the results yield `91`

```
var maxList = new List<object>
{
    10,
    50,
    90,
    "Hi",
    "!!!",
    "#123"
};

var incData = maxList.Where(m =>
{
    decimal temp;
    return decimal.TryParse(m.ToString(), out temp);
}).Max(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m));
incData++;
```